# Angular 2 : scope of services in lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm new to Angular 2 and working on a pre-existing template ([here](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/sing-app-web-angular-2.0-dashboard-WB0J6BJ85)).

I'm trying to use [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) but I have trouble using it **globaly**.

I have a layout module which declares some components (sidebar, navbar, notifications etc) and imports ng-translate service. In all of those components, I can access the translation service.

But, in this layout, I also have a Route which imports all content modules.

[image]

All the imported modules (dashboard, offers, contacts, agenda) can't access the translation service.

**I do not want to declare ng-translate in every child module, how can they access it ?**

Like I said, I'm new to Angular 2 and I'm completly lost in all these imports/delcarations/exports. Any help is appreciated.

Ps : sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figure it out.

First, I learn that what I'm doing with loadChildren is called Lazy loading (we learn every day). From that, research are easier.

I found the solution here :

https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate/issues/209

I don't really understand why but it's working.